# Search through list of countries with additional informations

Tags: jquery, json

Basically, I have a list of countries with latitude and longitude and want to calculate the distance between two countries.
So I put this information in JSON file, which looks like this

```
[
  {
    "country":"China",
    "latitude":35.0,
    "longitude":105.0,
    "continent":"Asia"
  },
  {
    "country":"India",
    "latitude":20.0,
    "longitude":77.0,
    "continent":"Asia"
  },
  ...
]
```

Then I load this file in jQuery: `$.getJSON( 'countries.json', function(data){ var json = data; });`

And now I would like to get the specific information as easy as `json.China.longitude`.
I know it doesn't work like this, but what would be the easiest way?

The calculation of the distance based on GPS coordinates is another thing, but I already found a function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that, it would be better for you to change your JSON to be more like, if it's possible of course.

```
[
{
    "China": {
        "latitude": 35,
        "longitude": 105,
        "continent": "Asia"
    },
    "India": {
        "latitude": 20,
        "longitude": 77,
        "continent": "Asia"
    }
}
```

]

Comment: This would be perfect. Is it possible to change my JSON to this in an automated way?

Comment: Well, I dont know if you are generating the file yourself or getting it from somewhere else. In the latter, you could read the file and for each entry you would get the country as a key for an array, and then json_encode and write it to write another file

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to update `countries.json` to return an object with the country as the key as this will save you some lookup time.  Otherwise you have to iterate over the array.  You could use native `filter`

```
var china = json.filter(function (elem) {
    return elem.country == "China";
})[0];
```

Or you could use something like [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#where)

Comment: Since it would appear that the OP is using country as a key of sorts, I would recommend using `_.find` instead of `_.where`.

Comment: Is it possible to make country the key in a automated way - I mean to change the structure of my JSON file?